# How do I add a div conditionally based on file name?

Tags: php, whmcs

I have put this code in **header.tpl** but the div is appearing on all pages

```
{if cart.php}
<div> This is Cart.PHP </div>
{/if}
```

I want this div to be appear in the header of **cart.php** page only.

Comment: `if condition` means there's a test. `if cart.php` implies that `if true, do` and in most languages, without a comparator, `if cart.php` translates to `if "cart.php"`, which will always (or at least usually) be true (yeah, "cart.php" *is*). What is being compared with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{if __FILE__ eq "cart.php"}
    do your thing
{/if}
```

Your comparison as @JaredFarrish says, will always return true since you are asking if the filename (in this case *cart.php* is *true*) and not if it's the current filename as you think you are.

This, however, may not work for includes (like your case) and you may want to use something like this:

```
{if $smarty.server.PHP_SELF eq "/cart.php"}
    do your thing
{/if}
```

**Note** that if your file is in a subdirectory you'd need to compare it to the full path or extract the filename from the string since `$smarty.server.PHP_SELF` returns the path too.

To do this you can use `basename` function directly to your variable, so doing `basename($smarty.server.PHP_SELF) eq "cart.php"` should be enough.

Comment: thanks it works, I just change the path to /my-whmcs-folder/cart.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the server variable PHP_SELF (change the "/cart.php" to the exact path from the root of your site to wherever the cart file is located.

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/cart.php") {
    echo "<div>This is cart.php</div>";
}
```

Comment: he is using smarty I assume, your answer is php only

Comment: @Juan - You assume, because [WHCMS uses Smarty](http://docs.whmcs.com/Client_Area_Template_Files)?